# What is the difference between \write16 and \message?

Tags: tex-core

`\write16` sends to terminal, `\message` also does this. Why there are two commands for this and in which cases each one must be used?

Comment: on can see `\message` like `\immediate\write` but there is an other difference that's each write start a new line and `\message` don't

Comment: [TeX by topics page 250](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/plain/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf#page=250)

Comment: See _The TeXbook_, bottom of page 227–top of page 228.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's in *D. Knuth*'s words

> An `‘\immediate\write16’` differs from `\message` in that `\write` prints
>   the text on a line by itself; the results of several `\message` commands
>   might appear on the same line, separated by spaces.

**Sample.tex**

```
First page
\write16{** one **}  \message{** two **}

\vfill\eject
Second page
\immediate\write16{** one W **}\immediate\write16{** two W **} 
\message{** one M **}\message{** two M **}
\bye
```

**sample.log** shows

```
(sample.tex ** two ** [1{[....]/texmfs/data/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}
** one **
]
** one W **
** two W **
** one M ** ** two M ** [2] )
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the sake of completeness, another difference is that LuaTeX supports more than 16 streams (it supports 128), therefore unlike `\message`, `\write16` might actually write to some code that allocates that stream.

Some alternatives include

- Lua's `print()`
- `\write128`, which is also valid in other engines
- `\message` with ^^J/whatever \newlinechar is at the end
- LaTeX's `\typeout` command which internally writes to the `\@unused` stream.

Remark, `morewrites` package does not touch stream 16 (it only uses 0-15 and 19...) so 16 is still safe.

---

Another difference, this one only for academical purpose, is that

- `\message` expands tokens as it goes, similar to `\csname … \endcsname`, `\pdfescapestring`, `\scantokens` or `\edef`.
- `\write16` needs to first collect the arguments unexpanded (like `\def` or `\toks0={…}`), then fully expand it <sub>([with an `\endwrite` token put after the `}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/649069/250119))</sub> when it needs to be written.

  `\immediate\write16` inherits this behavior as well. (it could do differently, but I assume this is for implementation simplicity)

Consequently, in these cases the behavior is different:

```
% given this.
\outer\def\someoutertoken{}

% then...
\message{123 \noexpand\someoutertoken}  % works
%\immediate\write16{123 \noexpand\someoutertoken}  % fails

\message{\iffalse}{\fi}  % works
%\immediate\write16{\iffalse}{\fi}   % fails, produces a "incomplete iffalse" error message just like "\iffalse\someoutertoken\fi"
```